# Return nodes of unique values based on 2 key parameters in XSLT1.0

Tags: xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

Have the following input

```
<LIN>
      <REF>
        <D_127>EQ</D_127>
      </S_REF>
      <L_SDP>
        <S_FST>
          <D_127>D0317D02</D_127>
        </S_FST>
      </L_SDP>
      <L_SDP>
        <S_FST>
          <D_127>D0317D03</D_127>
        </S_FST>
      </L_SDP>
      <L_SDP>
        <S_FST>
          <D_127>D0317D04</D_127>
        </S_FST>
      </L_SDP>
    </L_LIN>
    <L_LIN>
      <S_REF>
        <D_127>1A</D_127>
      </S_REF>
      <L_SDP>
        <S_FST>
          <D_127>D0317D02</D_127>
        </S_FST>
      </L_SDP>
    </L_LIN>
    <L_LIN>
      <S_REF>
        <D_127>1A</D_127>
      </S_REF>
      <L_SDP>
      <S_FST>
          <D_127>D0317D02</D_127>
        </S_FST>
      </L_SDP>
    </L_LIN>
```

Would now like to have the following output

```
<DOC>
    <ITEM>
    <D_127>EQ</D_127>
    <D_127>D0317D02</D_127>
    </ITEM>
    <ITEM>
    <D_127>EQ</D_127>
    <D_127>D0317D03</D_127>
    </ITEM>
    <ITEM>
    <D_127>EQ</D_127>
    <D_127>D0317D04</D_127>
    </ITEM>
    <ITEM>
    <D_127>1A</D_127>
    <D_127>D0317D02</D_127>
    </ITEM>
    </DOC>
```

i want unique based on ref value and fst value.like to have items with combination of unique REF(EQ or 1A ) with S_FST(D0317D02) values. I am using XSLT 1.0 .when i use generate id i am getting some missing values...tried many combinations but couldn't get it . used for each loop for ref and fst values but couldn't get the required no of lines with combination.

Comment: *"I am using XSLT 1.0"* Then why is your question tagged as `xslt-2.0`?

Answer (score 0):

As with most (advanced) grouping tasks in XSLT 1, declare a key, here one that concatenates the two values, then process only the first item for each group established by the key:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:key name="group" match="S_FST/D_127" use="concat(., '|', ancestor::L_LIN/S_REF/D_127)"/>

  <xsl:template match="ROOT">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates 
            select="//S_FST/D_127[generate-id() = generate-id(key('group', concat(., '|', ancestor::L_LIN/S_REF/D_127))[1])]"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="S_FST/D_127">
      <ITEM>
          <xsl:copy-of select="ancestor::L_LIN/S_REF/D_127"/>
          <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
      </ITEM>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bEJbVrb